# Pack all files in a folder except for one file in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to pack all files in a folder like so:

```
Source: "...Src\*";DestDir:"{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

But I want it to pack all files inside `Src` except for 1 file.

Hopefully there is some code to exempt a file from being packed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To specify the file you want to exclude from your setup archive source use the [`Excludes`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Excludes) parameter:

```
[Files]
Source: "Src\*"; Excludes: "Src\SubFolder\FileToExclude.exe"; \
    DestDir:"{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```